# stored procedure arithmetic operation with casting

Tags: sql, function, postgresql, stored-procedures

I have a stored procedure on postgresql database. I have a problem when i try to make some arithmetic operation that involves typecasting. this is the code:

```
DECLARE 
myVar DOUBLE PRECISION;
myVar2 DOUBLE PRECISION;

BEGIN
SELECT CAST((row1/row2) AS DOUBLE PRECISION) FROM myTable WHERE row3 = "value" INTO myVar;
--row1 and row2 type are integer type
myVar = myVar + (myVar*40)/200;
myVar2 = myVar * $2;
--$2 is an integer argument of function
--other squeryes
END
```

Now when in the rest of code i'm using myVar2 inside INSERT query, the value added on my database is 0. Why? It looks like that my operation are wrong...

Comment: what is the initial data type of RoW1& ROW2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

please try

```
SELECT CAST(row1 AS DOUBLE PRECISION)/row2)  
FROM myTable 
WHERE row3 = "value" INTO myVar;
```

Let me know if it work.

Regards

Ashutosh Arya

Comment: If you post code, XML or data samples, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: As a good rule always cast your datatypes explicitly when your doing something like this, worst case it makes it easier to read what datatypes things are.  Best case you avoid a bug.